# setInterval, clearInterval, setTimeout conflict messing up slideshow

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I've got a slideshow that autoplays on document.ready by triggering my left arrow click on setInterval. I'm trying to stop the autoplay when the nav arrows are clicked, while still allowing the arrows to navigate the slides.

This accomplishes that.

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(switchLeft, 4000);

$("#leftarrow, #rightarrow").click(function() {
    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

But I want the autoplay to kick back in if the arrows haven't been clicked in 8 seconds. I have tried turning the setInterval back in by adding this setTimeout into the click function, but it counts all the clicks of user navigation during the pause and starts throwing my slides around like crazy. (I've got two layers of images moving on every click.)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  intervalId = window.setInterval(switchLeft, 4000)
}, 8000);
```

I've tried wrapping stuff in a setTimeout function but I just end up getting different weirdness.

Thanks for any help,
Charlie Magee

Comment: Please provide us a jsfiddle so we can help you easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the `setTimeout()` if the arrows are clicked before it fires so you don't get multiple timers going at once (which will certainly exhibit weirdness).

I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do on the arrows, but this code should manage the timers:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(switchLeft, 4000);
var timeoutId;

$("#leftarrow, #rightarrow").click(function() {

    // clear any relevant timers that might be going 
    // so we never get multiple timers going
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    // restart the interval in 8 seconds
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        intervalId = window.setInterval(switchLeft, 4000)
    }, 8000);
});
```

Comment: Your example does the same thing that mine did. switchLeft is my function that is also triggered by the left arrow. It sends slides from right to left. switchRight does the opposite. No timers hidden in them. If I click the right arrow a few times, then the left arrow then pretty soon everything is moving back and forth all over the place as they try to catch up with the clicks and the setInterval. It's hilarious to watch, but not what I need. I think I need a way to stop the interval on the click, but then ignore this click function for the 8000.

Comment: Maybe something like doing the set and clear with transparent divs on top of the arrows that I show and hide with a setTimeout?

Comment: @charliemagee - I made one correction in the code (removed a `var` that your original code had so it is properly using the higher scoped variable).  This should help.  If your switchLeft function also has an animation in it, then you probably need to stop that animation also in the click function.  This now manages these timers appropriately.  If you want help with the rest of the problems, you will have to show us the rest of the code.

Comment: jfriend00 -- Perfect! I'm still stumbling on my scoping of variables, as you can see. My switchLeft and switchRight are full of animations, but it looks like only a couple of them need tweaking. Thanks much. By the way, how do you get the @ symbol in front of my username? I couldn't find it in stackoverflow faqs.

Comment: @charliemagee - I just type the "@" manually and then the first couple letters of your name and it offers autocompletion on people involved in this question.  `@username` makes sure that that person gets notified of your comment, though an answerer is automatically notified of any comments on their answer and a questioner is automatically notified of any comments on their question.